# Javascript while loop failure

Tags: javascript

Into a php page I have 20 text boxes. I want to make a button, using javascript, and when user clicks on it the rest 19 text boxes to take 1st text box's text. I have done something like this but it isn't working... Any idea?

```
function Throw_PhotoStuff(){
    var pcount=1; 
    while(pcount<20;){
      document.getElementById('photo_'+pcount).value = document.getElementById('photo_1').value; pcount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: your code looks good. Where is the html? And what isn't working? Any error in console?

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners)

Comment: As Sudhir wrote below, it was a syntax error. I should remove the semicolon from `while(pcount<20;)` to `while(pcount<20)`. Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the semicolon from while loop, like:

```
while(pcount<20;){  //will show SyntaxError: missing ) after condition
```

to

```
while(pcount<20){
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have extra semicolon here 
**while(pcount<20;){**

remove this